# Create a new list enumerating the random integers from another list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, random, integer

I need to simulate a certain scenario.

So I'm defining a variable which generates a loop of a random number of integers.

I get for example:

```
list = [2, 35, 4, 8, 56, 10]
```

Then, I'm generating this random list 50 times through another loop and I store the data into a dictionary to visualize a Pandas Dataframe.

```
data_dict = {'random_numers': list}
data_dict_pd = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

So I get for example this:

```
[1, 16, 6, 6, 1, 10]
[3, 8, 4, 4, 1, 20, 7, 25, 12]
[14, 8, 16, 4, 11, 18, 5, 15, 24, 2, 15, 5]
[7, 24, 1, 14]
[5, 14, 19, 24, 1]
... 50 times.
```

Now, I need to create another column enumerating each number in each list of elements, to get the following, based on the previous results:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
...50 times.
```

Actually, came up with the following but it's wrong:

```
new_list = []
 for index in enumerate(list)
    new_list.append(index)
```

Any better idea?

Comment: How's it "wrong"? Aren't you just looking for `list(range(1, len(lst) + 1))`…?

Comment: @deceze this will cause `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` error since OP has renamed `list`

Comment: @Selnay That's a bug in OP's code…

Comment: It's wrong because it's enumerating the hole string instead of the single elements of the list. In fact it returns 1 ofr the first string, 2 for the second etc. Instead, I need to enumerate the single elements into the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest changing the name of your list, as `list` is used for Python lists.

Assuming you change it to `l`, I would use:

```py
l = [2, 35, 4, 8, 56, 10]
new_list = []
for i in range(1, len(l) + 1):
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Output:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

If what you need is to iterate a list of lists, and incorporating @deceze suggestions (provided that you don't rename `list`):

```py
lists = [
    [1, 16, 6, 6, 1, 10],
    [3, 8, 4, 4, 1, 20, 7, 25, 12],
    [14, 8, 16, 4, 11, 18, 5, 15, 24, 2, 15, 5],
    [7, 24, 1, 14],
    [5, 14, 19, 24, 1]
]

new_lists = [list(range(1, len(lst) + 1)) for lst in lists]
print(new_lists)
```

Output:
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

Comment: This is invalid syntax, and it could be simplified a lot to just `list(range(1, len(l) + 1))`. Depending on whether OP actually needs a list or not, you can probably also omit the `list()`.

Comment: I have corrected the syntax. Also, I cannot use `list()` if the OP has used that name in his code for the actual list of data. I have used that approach in case OP does not want to change the name

Comment: @Foldhy I have added the output I get. Seems correct to me.

Comment: Seems good by yourside but I don't understand why I get this instead:
[7, 8, 1, 14, 19, 5, 18, 7, 11, 4, 15]                 1
[16, 7, 6, 3, 13, 2, 20, 1, 11, 7, 16, 2, 5]          2
[15, 1, 1, 13, 13, 17, 2, 13, 6, 13, 8, 7]            3
[2, 15, 4, 20, 18, 2, 8, 15, 1, 5, 9, 1, 7, 2]        4
[18, 10, 4, 19, 5, 3, 6, 15, 8, 20, 1]                   5

Comment: Could you please share the code that is producing that input?

Comment: Ok, I just introduced also your second part of code and it works properly. I've upvoted you on both answers. Many thanks! (probably, it won't show up the vote since I'm new)

Answer (score 0):

```py
new_list = []
for index in range(1,len(list)+1)
    new_list.append(index)
```

should be used in place of enumerator,as it will going to return the pair.

Thank you,

Comment: Hi Raja, is just not working. It's enumerating the hole string of random numbers. Instead I need to enumerate the single elements of random numbers and create another list.